# conditions to terminate a for loop with numbers

Tags: for-loop

I am unsure of the condition to terminate the loop in this question.

In the following program, which condition must be satisfied for the loop to terminate (i.e., skip
Ln 2 and go to Ln 3)? (Ln 1 is the for loop)

```
for i in range(2, 4, 1): 
    print(i)
```

the options i have are:

A. 2 < 4

B. i - 1 > 4

C. 2 >= 4

D. i < 2

E. i >= 4

I assume that A and C is wrong as it does not make sense as it return True and False
I am thinking it is B as i>5 is out of range and loop is terminated but at the same time option D also seemed out of range.

Please help me clarify this thank you.

Comment: Would you explain more? You can simply put as many as `if` conditions before `print` statement that you want, and print based on your conditions.

Comment: that is all the question gives. I think you only choose one condition from the multiple choice that satisfy the question. After reading your comment i think i understood the question better now. So the multiple choice are the `if` condition that will be put into the code. Which in this case the answer should be C as the `if` statement will always return False and print statement will never occur?

Comment: Well, if you want to just choose from A to E for a condition not to print, B and D are always false also.